# java generics and collection assignment

Tags: java, generics, collections

If I have this class:

```
class Foo<T> implements SomeInterface
{
    final private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    final private Class<? extends T> runtimeClass;

    public Foo(Class<? extends T> cl) { this.runtimeClass = cl; }

    // method override from SomeInterface
    @Override public boolean addChild(Object o)   
    {
        // Only add to list if the object is an acceptible type.
        if (this.runtimeClass.isInstance(o))
        {
            list.add( /* ??? how do we cast o to type T??? */ );
        }
    }

    public List<T> getList() 
    { 
        return this.list; 
    } // yes, I know, this isn't safe publishing....
}
```

how would I perform a runtime cast from Object to type T?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
list.add(this.runtimeClass.cast(o))
```

See `Class.`[`cast()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) for details

Comment: huh. that seems weird somehow... I am casting up from Object to something that extends T, then downcasting to T when it gets added to the list....

Comment: If that is a concern, then make runtimeClass Class<T> instead of Class<? extends T>. That would ensure that all instances of T would be added to the list, not just instances of runtimeClass, because runtimeClass would be T.

Comment: @Jason: if that seems weird, then your initial .isInstance() check is weird for exactly the same reason: why would you want to check if the value is some type that extends T instead of checking for T directly? And if you in fact check for `runtimeClass`, then casting to anything *but* `runtimeClass` is certainly on the weird side.

Answer (score 1):

```
// method override from SomeInterface    
@Override public boolean addChild(Object o)       
{        
     // Only add to list if the object is an acceptible type.        
     if (this.runtimeClass.isInstance(o))        
     {            
         list.add((T)o);        
     }    
}
```

Comment: This code will produce a warning. While the code should never throw a ClassCastException (as long as no other ugly casting is done), it is still better to avoid that warning by using Class.cast().

Comment: You can use the @SuppressWarnings("I am sure this is of Type T") to ignore the warning, but I do agree its not really 100% safe.